# WARN: [logback.groovy] (or logback.xml) occurs multiple times on classpath if logback is used in a GWT project

Tags: gwt, logback, logback-groovy

if you just put some `logback.groovy` (or `logback.xml`) file in the (recommended) `src/logback.groovy` location you will likely run into a similar (console) warning:

```
13:21:08,177 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.groovy] at [file:/D:/my-proj-gwt/src-resource/logback.groovy]
13:21:08,178 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback.groovy] occurs multiple times on the classpath.
13:21:08,178 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback.groovy] occurs at [file:/D:/my-proj-gwt/war/WEB-INF/classes/logback.groovy]
13:21:08,178 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback.groovy] occurs at [file:/D:/my-proj-gwt/src-resource/logback.groovy]
```

with logging detail output included. The logging `INFO` output is included because of the *multiple occurances* of the logback config file(s) in the classpath (`src/` and `war/WEB-INF/classes`).

I found out the way to solve this as answered below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some fiddling I found a solution to this one:

1. **move `src/logback.groovy` (or `logback.xml`) to `src-resource/logback.groovy`**

   - create the folder or similar as it may not exist
2. **add `src-resources/` to your *Java Build Path* and adjust its `Output Folder` to `war/WEB-INF/classes`** (or the same as your `src/` *Output Folder*)
3. **remove `src-resources/` from your *Web Application*s - *Run/Debug Configuration*s - *Classpath***

   - created in Eclipse after *`<your project>` -> Run As -> Web Application* and look then under *Run -> Run Configurations ...*
   - the `src/`folder needs to stay in there so GWT is able to compile the *JavaScript* sources for the client

(my setup: *Eclipse Kepler*, *GWT 2.6.0*, *logback 1.1.2*)